# Possible to bypass Google Verification on Login with Selenium PhantomJS?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I wanted to write a bot to scrape long-time statistics on https://www.bustabit.com/
but I realized they have a google verification on the login form.
Now I was wondering if it's even possible to bypass this security.

I'm using Python with Selenium and PhantomJS

I was thinking about passing PhantomJS Cookies/Sessions from my Chrome Browser after I logged in, so it would auto-connect on Site visit - but is this even possible?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's login verification is literally designed to stop bots from being authenticated. I would also not suggest attempting to brute force these puzzles, it's more trouble than its worth.

Depending on how often you create a new web session, you could just navigate to the login page, enter the credentials and then pause the script and prompt a *human* to solve the captcha, before handing the controls back to selenium.

Comment: That would be fine too, the only part stopping me is the one-time login to just be in. :)
Does selenium come with the feature to stop the script, give me a head of a Browser to wait for input and then work headless again?
Because as far as I could tell now I'd have to start chromedriver again to see a gui, but chromedrivers login shouldn't affect PhantomJS's login I guess. :/

Comment: Headless makes things a bit trickier as you can't just watch the screen and click on the elements. I'm assuming the google verification is that small window that appears asking you to choose from a list of images that meet a certain criteria. Perhaps you could create a gui that shows these images and the criteria for passing the test. After selecting the images in this gui, selenium would know which images to click on the headless browser.

Or maybe there's a way to toggle headless browsing, that would be a lot easier.

Comment: You got me on the right path, thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: http://scraping.pro/recaptcha-solve-selenium-python/

As far as I am concerned there is nothing publically available that would be able to solve the puzzles. And if there would be, google would quickly fix it. Therefore your best bet would be to bruteforce it. If that still works.